# SHRINK mySQL BLOB данные

Tags: python, mysql, blob

```python
def delete_picture(picture_id,cur,conn):
cur.execute("UPDATE pictures SET picture_bytes = NULL WHERE id = %s",(picture_id,))
cur.execute("DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = %s",(picture_id,))
conn.commit()
```

Использую библиотеку pysql, которая подключается к mysql на сервере ubuntu.

У меня есть тг бот на питоне, который забирает картинки с дб в BLOB данных. Картинки загружаются с другого компа. После вызова функции, представленной выше картинки удаляются из таблицы, но память занимаемая ими не отчищается из-за этого сервер переполняется и бот перестает работать. Что нужно сделать, чтобы после удаления картинки она не занимала память на сервере?

SHRINKIN не вариант, потому что использую mysql

Comment: а с какой целью вы в БД файлы храните?

Comment: Передача их между несколькими пк, находящихся в разных местах планеты

Comment: что мешает для этих целей файловые хранилища использовать? свой хостинг или облачный.